# Show base64 encoded data in new tab Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am receiving a PDF file in base64 form. I want to show it in a new tab. 
I tried this -

This is my controller code for sending the data back to browser

```
send_data Base64.decode64(params[:base64_file]), :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => "#{params[:name]}.pdf", :disposition => "inline"
```

View file :

```
<a href='<%= show_pdf_url({:pdf_body => pdf_body, :name => "download.pdf" %>' target='_blank'>
```

But it throws 'Request entity too large' error.

Tried to change it to post request by -

```
<a href='#' class='pdf-download'/>
```

and calling -

```
$('.pdf-download').on('click', function(event){
var get_all_admin = jQuery(this);
var w = window.open('about:blank');
w.document.body.appendChild(w.document.createElement('iframe')).src = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,${get_all_admin.data("base64_file")}';
```

but it does nothing, and end up loading the same page in new tab.

Help me out, I am stuck here.

Comment: This is issue with the server that handling your download request. Can you let us know what are server are you using for running rails? Do you use any reverse proxy server like Nginx/Apache?

Comment: Yes, I am using a reverse proxy. But I doubt that should be the case, because I have one more API call where instead of base64, I am returning file, which works well with send_data

Comment: Can you explain more , because there is no params[:base64_file] and params[:name] in api call that is passed to controller. Also, if you are saving the uploaded base64 file, then you can try using send_file instead of send_data.

Comment: Oh, consider I am sending it. BTW I found one solution that works for me. Will post that here soon.

Comment: Great.! share us the solution with cause of this problem as well. Which will help others to understand the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Added my solution @dharmesh

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up using this -
Instead to trying to appending it to the new iFrame, I wrote the output to the iFrame. I really wished I was able to solve this using `send_data` -

```
   $(document).on('click', '.pdf-download', function(event){
    var get_all_admin = jQuery(this);
    event.preventDefault();

    let pdfWindow = window.open("")
    pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe style='position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;' width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(get_all_admin.data("base64_file"))+"'></iframe>")
  });
```

Where get_all_admin gets data that I set in my url like this -

```
<a href='#' data-base64_file='<%=mydoc.body%>' data-name='<%= get_pdf_name(mydoc.id, mydoc.invoice_date) %>' target='_blank' class='pdf-download' >
```

here mydoc is the output in which I am getting the pdf file in Base64 format.

Comment: What the size of mydoc.body ?

Comment: That file is usually 100kbs. So when I pass it in a get request, it throws 'request entity too large'.

Comment: It's obvious: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: You have to open link with `doc.id` in new tab(`target='_blank'`) instead of trying to hack that limit.

Comment: That's what I did, changed it post request and handled everything in javascript only.

Comment: It doesn't look so: `data-base64_file='<%=mydoc.body%>'` and `src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + ...`

Comment: My bad, I didn't use post then, and handled it in javascript only.